# How to add the numeric values of properties of a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, operators

I'm trying to figure out how to make a function that adds the values of the elements chosen by the user and be able to display the results via prompt and console.log. Also, I'm wondering if there is a way to do it in which I don't need to specify the elements selected in order for the function to find within the code which elements were selected and execute the addition function. Because obviously if the list of options were longer I wouldn't want to have to make a new function for each potential combination of selections. As a side note, I guess the same problem would apply to the if statements, would switch statements be the most efficient way to tackle needs for "DRY" code in that instance?

My javascript code: *Please assume that the user selects only the first elements of the nested arrays. Also, that term "one" is worth $8.*

```
var selection = new Array (3);
selection[0] = new Array ('$1', '$2', '$3', '$4', '$5', '$6', '$7', '$8');
selection[1] = new Array ('phone1', 'phone2', 'phone3');
selection[2] = new Array ('one', 'two', 'three');


function pickPhone () {
    var yourPhone = prompt("pick phone: phone1: $1, phone2: $2, phone3: $3");

        if (yourPhone == selection[1][0]) {
        console.log(selection[1][0] + " will cost: " + selection[0][0]);
        alert(selection[1][0] + " will cost: " + selection[0][0]);
            pickTerm ();
        } if (yourPhone == "phone2") {
            alert(selection[1][1] + " will cost: " + selection[0][1]);
        } if (yourPhone == "phone3") {
            alert(selection[1][2] + " will cost: " + selection[0][2]);
        }

}


function pickTerm () {
    var yourTerm = prompt("pick term: one, two or three?");

        if (yourTerm == selection[2][0]) {
            alert("Your total so far is: ??");
        }
}

pickPhone ();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You are probably better off to use an object like: `var data = {costs:[1,2,3], phones:[1,2,3], other:[1,2,3]}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that keeps your arrays

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/o10ezyun/

JS

```
var selection = new Array(3);
selection[0] = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
selection[1] = new Array('phone1', 'phone2', 'phone3');
selection[2] = new Array('one', 'two', 'three');

var firstValue;

function pickPhone() {
    var yourPhone = prompt("pick phone: phone1: $1, phone2: $2, phone3: $3"),
        index = selection[1].indexOf(yourPhone);

    if(!~index){
        pickPhone();
    }else{
        firstValue = selection[0][index];
        alert(selection[1][index] + " will cost: $" + firstValue);
        pickTerm();    
    }
}


function pickTerm() {
    var yourTerm = prompt("pick term: one, two or three?"),
        index = selection[2].indexOf(yourTerm),
        finalValue = '$'+(firstValue+selection[0][index]);

    if(!~index){
        pickTerm();
    }else{
        alert("Your total so far is: "+finalValue);
    }
}

pickPhone();
```

Comment: This looks promising, i'm going to investigate this and will get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I can't really understand this, I guess I should have mentioned I'm a beginner. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure what problem you are actually solving.
How long these lists are (phones, costs, etc)?
What type of mapping is set for those items?

For now I'd recommend to merge corresponding values in objects like this:

```
// item -> cost
var phones = [
        {title: 'phone1', cost: '$1'},
        {title: 'phone2', cost: '$2'},
        {title: 'phone3', cost: '$3'}
    ],

    terms = [
        {title: 'one', cost: '$8'},
        {title: 'two', cost: '$2'},
        {title: 'three', cost: '$3'}
    ],

    phonesListWithCosts = (function(list) {
        return list.reduce(function(memo, item) {
            return memo + item.title + ': ' + item.cost;
        }, '');
    }(phones)),

    termsList = (function(list) {
        return list.reduce(function(memo, item) {
            return memo + ', ' + item.title;
        }, '');
    }(terms)),

    findBy = function(array, property, value) {
        return array.filter(function(item) {
            return item[property] === value;
        })[0];
    },

    getItem = function(list, promptMessage) {
        var selectedItemTitle = prompt(promptMessage);

        return findBy(list, 'title', selectedItemTitle);
    },

    getItemCost = function(item) {
        return parseInt(item.cost.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
    },

    pickPhone = function() {
        var selectedPhone = getItem(phones, 'pick phone: ' + phonesListWithCosts),
            firstPhone = phones[0],
            message;

        if (selectedPhone) {
            message = [selectedPhone.title, 'will cost:', selectedPhone.cost].join(' ');

            console.log(message);
            alert(message);

            if (selectedPhone === firstPhone) {
                pickTerm(getItemCost(selectedPhone));
            }
        }
    },

    pickTerm = function(accumCost) {
        var selectedTerm = getItem(terms, 'pick term: ' + termsList),
            totalCost,
            message;

        if (selectedTerm) {
            totalCost = accumCost + getItemCost(selectedTerm);
            message = 'Your total so far is: $' + totalCost;

            alert(message);
        }
    };

pickPhone();
```

[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/rapazodemebu/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: I cant use switches or objects to do it.

Comment: Why? Could you give more details?

Comment: its a school assignment.